# Using local packages with gb

Tags: go

I'm starting a new project and considering `gb` as my build tool but it doesn't appear to be integrating very well with `vscode`...

I've referenced 3rd party dependencies no problem using `gb vendor fetch` but as for creating local packages, this is proving a little trickier!  Am I missing something obvious?

Here's my local src directory:

```
src
    /cmd
        /model
            calc.go
        /server
            server.go
```

The following code compiles and creates a `bin\server.exe` file successfully but the import path isn't picked up, nor does `gocode` recognise it

Here's the server code:

```
package main

import (
    "cmd/model" // not a happy reference...
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(model.Add(1, 2))
}
```

Here's the model code:

```
package model

func Add(a int, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
```

I've found what appears to be a similar issue on Github (https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus/issues/325) and while nsf's solution sorts out auto-complete (post import), the import statement itself still claims to be searching in the GOROOT and GOPATHs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to an answer from lukehoban here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/249 I was able to get my environment working.

I simply created a settings.json file under the .vscode directory (which will now have to be checked in) into which I've configured:

```
{
    "go.gopath": "${workspaceRoot}"
}
```

This makes me feel unclean and it **still doesn't provide a way to reference both 3rd party dependencies and local packages together...**

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to work against Go, work with Go.

First of all give all your packages fully qualified import paths. Go is designed around global import paths, do not try to force Go into using flat hierarchies or even relative paths.

You can point to your import path repository endpoints either directly or by using Go's [remote import path](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths) mechanism. BTW, if you happen to run a self-hosted GitLab instance, it supports remote import path meta tags out of the box.

I prefer [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide), but maybe the following is possible with gb, too. Certainly something simililar will be possible with the upcoming [go dep](https://github.com/golang/dep):  You can point to ssh+git endpoints and others using glide's [repo stanza](https://glide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glide.yaml/). Frankly I have no idea if gb supports an equivalent mechanism, but if it doesn't this is a good reason to reconsider.

Comment: GB treats each project as its own GOPATH, so it's not something I'd normally do!  I ended up implementing govendor, which is working nicely.  I'm hanging on for dep too, something official will be a nice change to the plethora of solutions available at the moment...